# Missing "WebDavUrl" from GetDriveItem API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve `WebDavUrl` along with the rest of the data. I am using the below approach

```
 public DriveItem getDriveItemWebDavUrl(String driveId, String itemId) {
    return graphClient.drives(driveId)
            .items(itemId)
            .buildRequest()
            .select("*,webDavUrl")
            .get();
}
```

and I can see below url generated by graph API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}?select=*%2CwebDavUrl
```

But the Graph API does not return `webDavUrl` along with the response. When I use the same URL in GraphExplorer it works as expected.

I'll appreciate any suggestions or feedback

Comment: Quite strange but in Graph Explorer ?select=*,webDavUrl returns webDavUrl but select with $ ?$select=*,webDavUrl doesn't return webDavUrl. I guess that it will be somehow connected to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, If we use QueryOption then it works like charm.

```
 public DriveItem getDriveItemWebDavUrl(String driveId, String itemId) {
      return graphClient.drives(driveId)
        .items(itemId)
        .buildRequest(List.of(new QueryOption("select", "*,webDavUrl")))
        .get();}
```